# How to display HTML tags properly from a text file using C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

So right now I'm using something like this in C#:

```
Response.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(line));
```

This will grab a line from a text file and display the stuff on screen - it works. My goal was to have the lines from the text file show something like this (HTML formatting in lines of text file):

```html
<a href='http://www.url.com' target='_blank'>Link</a><br><br><!--info-->
```

Unfortunately, for some reason the `<` and `>` are being converted to `&lt;` and `&gt;` before it gets turned into HTML, which exposes all the HTML code as text and simply doesn't work. I have tried looking into the WebBrowser control and stuff but I don't understand what I'm supposed to do. For example, I tried this from a site:

```
WebBrowser browser = new WebBrowser();
browser.Navigate("about:blank");
browser.Document.Write(Server.HtmlEncode(line));
```

...but it didn't work. I'm looking for something very simple and with a clear example I can mimic, if possible. Thanks! I will make sure to select an answer too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Other than that you are explicitly encoding the `<` and `>` brackets into `&lt;` and it's counterpart, I don't see any error.

Drop the `Server.HtmlEncode()` part and it should work.

```
Response.Write(line);
```

`Server.HtmlEncode()` will explicitly encode everything into so-called "entities", which are those `&lt;` codes. It is usually used to protect yourself from user-entered raw strings that should not modify your site's behaviour.

Comment: That did the trick exactly. I thought the HtmlEncode part was necessary, for security reasons. Also, I come from a PHP background, so a lot of this sanitizing/conversion data stuff is new to me. Thanks. Will select this as answer when I am allowed to.

Comment: It is necessary if the things you are dropping onto the site are user-generated and should never change the behaviour of your site. Use `HtmlEncode` when the text you are writing to the response comes from an unknown source to protect yourself from, for example, cross site scripting attacks.